# Attempted to call method "share" on class "Silex\Application" in Silex 2

Tags: symfony, silex

I am developing a project with silex-skeleton in its most recent version. When trying to use the share method shows me the following error:

Code:

```
$app['login'] = $app->share(function() use($app) {
    return new Model\UserModel($app);
});
```

Error:
**Attempted to call method "share" on class "Silex\Application"**

Any suggestions or possible cause of this failure

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Silex 2.0 is using Pimple 3.0 which has removed the `shared` method, now all services are shared by default, if you want a new instance you must call the `factory` method as stated in the [changelog for version 2.0](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/master/CHANGELOG).

So if you want a *login* service you should create it like this:

```
<?php

$app['login'] = function($app) {
    return new Model\UserModel($app);
};
```

You can take a look at the docs for the 3.0 Pimple version directly on [it's GitHub repository](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple)

<del>PS: Keep in mind that, at the time of this writing, Silex 2.0 is in **development**, so be prepared to adapt your code until it gets a 2.0 stable version.</del> [2.0 has reached prod status as of 2016-05-18](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/changelog.html#id2)

Comment: Thanks mTorres, i have shared in my social networks, actually use much time trying to find the answer.

regards

Comment: You are welcome @LuisFernandoCzaresBulbarela. If my answer really solves your problem, you should accept it and mark this question closed. See the [SO help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.