# Migrating from Silex to Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm in the middle of migrating some Silex code to a Symfony project..I was wondering what the Symfony equivalent is for registering Pimple services like these:

```
$app['service.test1'] = $app->protect(...)
$app['service.test2'] = $app->share(...)
```

Any other pointers are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) on the service container for a basic understanding of services.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28164936/1196369) answer `share` was removed in new versions of Silex. `share` seems to equate to regular service definitions you'll read about in the symfony docs.

I've never used anything like `protect` in Symfony, I suppose you could declare a class with and use the `__invoke` method for your function.

```
class Adder
{
  public function __invoke($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
  }
}
```

Then inside `YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`

```
services:
  adder:
    class: MyNamespace\Adder
```

And you could use it like so:

```
$adder = $this->container->get('adder');
$result = $adder(1,2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Register your services with the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). Symfony doesn't use Pimple.